# Othographic projection causing geometry to get clipped by the far plane

Tags: opengl, clipping, orthographic

Let's say I have a rectangle that I want to render oriented 45 degrees about the x-axis to the camera. So it looks like this:

[image]

(clipped at the bottom only because it's the edge of the window).

As I shift this rectangle along it's local y-direction though (i.e. increase y on it's vertices before we rotate it about the x-axis) then it eventually gets clipped by the far plane:

[image]

How do I prevent this? It seems unnatural that the rectangle should be cut off at all when moved away from the viewport but still within actual view.

I do definitely want to render my rectangles orthographically.

I am quite new to OpenGL so I'm thinking I'm missing something here.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Could you give a little more detail? Do you mean just shift the rectangle back down it's local y? The whole problem is that I want to shift it up in the first place.

Comment: @Rabbid76 You seem to have deleted your comment and re-added it

Comment: You will not get any further details without posting any code. Your question is unclear. The context is missing. However, if the object is clipped by the far plane, either increase the distance to the far plane or shift the object along the view space z axis.

Comment: @Rabbid76 A fair point but the code is quite long and convoluted. I will see if I can trim it down...

Comment: @Rabbid76 I expect your suggestion to just move stuff down the global z-axis will probably be the correct answer. I was just interested if there was more to know about this far-plane clipping

Comment: The orthographic projection matrix defined a cuboid volume. All geometry that is outside of this volume is clipped. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick it turns out is just to squish the z position of the vertices in the vertex shader. This way more vertices can fit inside the frustrum. This does distort the mesh but in orthographic projection this actually doesn't make a visible difference (at least in my situation).

I.e. inside the vertex shader do this:

```
gl_Position.z *= 0.5; // or whatever scale you want
```